# Spring MVC using Hibernate and maven

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Good day i am using hibernate with mysql database but when trying to run my project i am getting the error Severe:   Exception while loading the app Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /eLeon Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.websirmbano.springmvc.dao.OipatientDao below are my classes and my configuration files

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.websirmbano.springmvc.dao;

import com.websirmbano.springmvc.model.Tblpatients;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.SQLQuery;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

/**
 *
 * @author SYSTEMS DEVELOPER ML
 */

@Repository
public class OIPatientDaoImpl   implements OipatientDao {

@Autowired
    private HibernateTemplate  hibernateTemplate;
    @Override
    public Tblpatients getOIPatientById(String patientId ) {
        return hibernateTemplate.get(Tblpatients.class, patientId);
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public List<Tblpatients> findAllOIPatients() {
        String hql = "FROM Tblpatients as p ORDER BY p.patientId";
        return (List<Tblpatients>) hibernateTemplate.find(hql);
    }   
    @Override
    public void addOIPatient(Tblpatients patient) {
        hibernateTemplate.save(patient);
    }
    @Override
    public void updateOIPatient(Tblpatients patient) {
        Tblpatients p = getOIPatientById(patient.getPatientId());
        p.setFirstName(patient.getFirstName());
        p.setSurName(patient.getSurName());
        p.setSex(patient.getSex());
        p.setDateOfBirth(patient.getDateOfBirth());
        p.setDateOfDeath(patient.getDateOfDeath());
        hibernateTemplate.update(p);
    }
    @Override
    public void deleteOIPatientById(String patientId) {
        hibernateTemplate.delete(getOIPatientById(patientId));
    }

        @Override
        public List findOIPatientByParameter(String patientId, String firstName, String surName,String nationalId){
        String queryPatient="SELECT * from Tblpatients where 1 = Case when '" + patientId + "'='' Then 1 when patientId = '" + patientId + "' AND 1 = Case when '" + nationalId + "'='' Then 1 when nationalId = '" + nationalId + "' AND 1= Case when '" + firstName + "'='' Then 1 when firstName = '" + firstName + "' AND 1 = Case when '" + surName + "'='' Then 1 when surName = '" + surName + "'";
        SQLQuery sqlQuery =hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession().createSQLQuery(queryPatient);
        List result = sqlQuery.list();
        return result;
        }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public boolean OIPatientExists(String patientId) {
        String hql = "FROM Tblpatients as p WHERE p.patientId = ?";
        List<Tblpatients> patient = (List<Tblpatients>) hibernateTemplate.find(hql, patientId);
        return patient.size() > 0 ? true : false;
    }
}



/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.websirmbano.springmvc.dao;

import com.websirmbano.springmvc.model.Tblpatients;
import java.util.List;

/**
 *
 * @author SYSTEMS DEVELOPER ML
 */
public interface OipatientDao {

    Tblpatients getOIPatientById(String patientId);

    void addOIPatient(Tblpatients patient);

    void updateOIPatient(Tblpatients patient);

    void deleteOIPatientById(String patientId);

    List<Tblpatients> findAllOIPatients();

    List findOIPatientByParameter(String patientId, String firstName, String surName,String nationalId);

    boolean OIPatientExists(String patientId);

}


and my configuration files are as follows

package com.websirmbano.springmvc.configuration;

import java.util.Locale;
import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.websirmbano.springmvc")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");

        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasename("messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
        @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver(){
        CookieLocaleResolver resolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        resolver.setDefaultLocale(new Locale("en"));
        resolver.setCookieName("myLocaleCookie");
        resolver.setCookieMaxAge(4800);
        return resolver;
    }
}



package com.websirmbano.springmvc.configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(AppConfig.class);
        ctx.setServletContext(container);

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = container.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));

        servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        servlet.addMapping("/");
    }

}


package com.websirmbano.springmvc.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan({ "com.websirmbano.springmvc.configuration" })
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class HibernateConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;
    @Bean
    public HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate() {
        return new HibernateTemplate((SessionFactory) sessionFactory());
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.websirmbano.springmvc.model" });
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());
        return sessionFactory;
     }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));
        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        return properties;        
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory s) {
       HibernateTransactionManager txManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
       txManager.setSessionFactory(s);
       return txManager;
    }
}

where am i getting it wrong 

regards 

leon
```

Comment: The exception states that catalina could not found the dao interface. Are you sure it is in the path?

Answer (score 0):

@EnableJpaRepositories("com.websirmbano.springmvc.dao") in HibernateConfiguration class.